# Include Angular 2 package in an Angular 2 JavaScript project

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I'm creating an Angular 2 application in plain javascript using [this quickstart boilerplate](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html).

I want to include my custom made Angular 2 package which is built by WebPack. Is this actually possible?  If so, what is the best way to do it?

At the moment, when I try to add `CustomModel` from the package to `app.module`, I get the following error:

```
Error: Unexpected value 'MyModule' imported by the module 'class1' at SyntaxError.ZoneAwareError
```

I have reproduced and example of this error here: https://plnkr.co/edit/FqgWgBj2xvPLJmkrsuz1

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the issue has to do with the way your child module is being created. As in [this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11438) or this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1831), you might need to this:

```
resolve: { 
     modules: [ path.join(projectRoot, "node_modules") ] 
}
```

> cause your node_modules won't be available from __dirname, __dirname
>   points to webpack.config folder
>
> PS: but if you have custom webpack compilation process, than probably
>   __dirname will work :)

Comment: This looks at for another case, mainly the problem is with combine angular 2 js with custom package